# Getting Maven to Report Which File Has Local Modifications

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that builds a simple Maven project. If all I do is build, it works just fine. The problem arises when I try and do a release, dry run or regular. It consistently fails with the `Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications` error. I have wiped out the workspace, but the problem persists. Is there any way I can get Maven to tell me **which** file it thinks has been modified? I would assume that by wiping out the local workspace and immediately running the dry run release that there wouldn't be any opportunity for anything to get modified.

Please note, I do **not** have access to the Jenkins server or the slave that is running the actual release build, so I can't use any tools there (like SVN) to determine what is supposedly modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the solution to my problem was to not use the "Local to the workspace" strategy for my private Maven repository in the Jenkins job configuration. By changing that to the "Local to the executor" strategy the problem went away. I'm still not sure why it was having the problem in the workspace, but this solution resolved it form me, and might work for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven SCM plugin to do a diff.

https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/diff-mojo.html

Basically, integrate the maven plugin upstream of the failure, and see if anything has been changed.  I imagine you might be able to see the output in the log, but if you cannot, you might be able to move your "real" maven pom.xml aside and replace it with one that generates a diff file and with the help of the maven build helper plugin, attaches that file as an additional aritfact (to a pom target).

Comment: keep in mind that the release plugin does a number of changes, if you are dealing with item in version control that shouldn't be (like checked in .class files) you might be spending some time telling your SCM to forget about versioning various files.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How do I go about integrating it? All I do now is hit the "Perform Maven Release" link for my project in Jenkins. As far as I know that runs "mvn -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare". How can I get the diff after the release has downloaded everything but before it does its own compare?